# How to un-default Emacs on Mac OS X 10?

Tags: macos, emacs

I’ve installed Emacs 24.4 on my Mac 10, and it took over the “default editor” role from my other editors (TextMAte, for example). How can I revert that without un-installing Emacs? Could not find options like that in Emacs Preferences.

Comment: Did newer versions of OSX do away with the option in Finder and other related applications to click on Info -- Command+i -- and select the default open-with application and then click the button Change All?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Download [RCDefaultApp](http://www.rubicode.com/Software/RCDefaultApp/). If the latest version does not work, try an older version. If you have 10.2 or above the latest version should work.

Open the file you download and then open `RCDefaultApp.prefPane`. Install it and go to the Apps tab. From there you can choose all available formats for each program!

Here is an image; make sure to click on "Set As Default" when you check the formats you want:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, but I really wanted to do it in "one shot" without going to each individual file types... There are many :)

Comment: please read above

Comment: thanks - it is pretty much what I want. I just wish there was also an option to assign , say, TextMate to "anything that does not have an explicit editor assigned' - kind of a default editor for anything. thanks!

Comment: This is what I use, very handy: http://apple.stackexchange.com/a/60626

Answer (score 0):

There is a environment variable called `$EDITOR`. But maybe it don't affect the things outside terminal.

Also you can try [RCDefaultApp](http://www.rubicode.com/Software/RCDefaultApp/)? But it seems a little old.